# RxJava2: Need help to convert java code into rx

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am newbie in RxJava and need help to improve my code. Here is what I've done:

```
public Single<List<MenuItemsBlocks>> loadMenuItemsBlocks() {

    Completable.fromAction(() -> DataStoreRepository.deleteMenuItemsBlock())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).blockingAwait();

    List<MenuItemsBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> aliasList = getAliasFromMenuItems();

    for (String alias : aliasList) {
        List<MenuItemsBlocks> itemsBlocks = ApiRepository.getMenuItemBlocks(alias)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                .map(item -> new MenuItemsBlocks(
                        item.getId(),
                        item.getType(),
                        item.getImagePosition(),
                        item.getTextField(),
                        item.getSortOrder(),
                        item.getFileTimeStamp(),
                        alias
                ))
                .doOnNext(block -> DataStoreRepository.saveMenuItemsBlock(block))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .toList()
                .blockingGet();

        blocks.addAll(itemsBlocks);
    }

    return Single.just(blocks);
}
```

There is no problem at runtime with this code, but I want to improve it in rx style, I've tried to rewrite it something like this (but it's not working):

```
public Single<List<MenuItemsBlocks>> loadMenuItemsBlocks() {

    Completable.fromAction(() -> DataStoreRepository.deleteMenuItemsBlock())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).blockingAwait();

    Set<String> aliasList = getAliasFromMenuItems();

    return Observable.fromIterable(aliasList)
            .switchMap(alias -> ApiRepository.getMenuItemBlocks(alias)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                    .map(item -> new MenuItemsBlocks(
                            item.getId(),
                            item.getType(),
                            item.getImagePosition(),
                            item.getTextField(),
                            item.getSortOrder(),
                            item.getFileTimeStamp(),
                            alias
                    ))
                    .doOnNext(block -> DataStoreRepository.saveMenuItemsBlock(block))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .toList()
            );
}
```

And I am stuck with it and need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have `blockingAwait` in non-test code, you are doing it wrong. Second, you probably need `concatMap` instead of `switchMap` as it will just keep switching to later list elements, cancelling the outstanding API calls.

```java
public Single<List<MenuItemsBlocks>> loadMenuItemsBlocks() {

    return Completable.fromAction(() -> DataStoreRepository.deleteMenuItemsBlock())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .andThen(Single.defer(() -> {
            Set<String> aliasList = getAliasFromMenuItems();

            return Observable.fromIterable(aliasList)
                .concatMap(alias -> ApiRepository.getMenuItemBlocks(alias)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                    .map(item -> new MenuItemsBlocks(
                        item.getId(),
                        item.getType(),
                        item.getImagePosition(),
                        item.getTextField(),
                        item.getSortOrder(),
                        item.getFileTimeStamp(),
                        alias
                    ))
                    .doOnNext(block -> DataStoreRepository.saveMenuItemsBlock(block))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                )
                .toList();
      }));
}
```

Comment: It helped, thanks for your response! blockingAwait is really bad practice, specifically in my case, removed it and UI stopped freezing. Thanks a lot!